# Angular-UI-Router not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, today I added angular-ui-router to my webapp. However, it's showing some really weird behaviour. It used to display the current page in the `ui-view`. So a page in a page.

Now, it's working correct, but it doesn't show subpages and I can't seem to figure out why.

**Main page**

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="ExampleApp">

    <head>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Example App</title>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div>    

            <div ui-view></div>

        </div>

        <!-- Angular -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js"></script>
        <!-- UI-Router -->
        <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <!-- Main app file -->
        <script src="/js/main.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

**main.js**

```
var ExampleApp = angular.module('ExampleApp', ['ui.router']);

ExampleApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  //
  // For any unmatched url, redirect to /home
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
  //
  // Now set up the states
  $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
          url: "/home",
          templateUrl: "views/home.html",
          controller: "MainController"
      })
      .state('settings', {
          url: "/settings",
          templateUrl: "views/settings.html",
          controller: "SettingsController"
      })
      .state('settings.account', {
          url: "/account",
          templateUrl: "views/settings.account.html",
          controller: "AccountSettingsController"
      });
});

ExampleApp.config(["$locationProvider", function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Comment: So to confirm the problem: the `home` and `settings` states display properly, but `settings.account` does not?

Comment: Well, it does if I click on `settings` and then on `account`. But if I go to `/settings/account` through the address bar in chrome, I get a blank page.

Comment: I've had this problem as well. Try a trailing slash when requesting the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
url:"settings/account",
```